# Qt propagates paint events on backgroung items

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I do have 2 QDeclarativeItems.

```
void BackgroundLayer::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QWidget* widget)
{
    painter->drawImage( QRectF(dx1, dy1, dx2-dx1, dy2-dy1), shownImage, QRectF(sx1, sy1, sx2-sx1, sy2-sy1) );
}

void ForegroundLayer::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QWidget* widget)
{
    QPen pen(Qt::red, 3, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap, Qt::RoundJoin);
    painter->setPen(pen);
    painter->drawLine(p1, p2);
}
```

QML

```
Rectangle {
    width: 1920
    height: 1080

    BackgroundLayer{
        id: background_layer
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    ForegroundLayer {
        id: foreground_layer
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

Drawing on ForegroundLayer triggers BackgroundLayer paint event, causing it to repaint the whole image. As a result, drawing works slow. Is it possible to avoid this and repaint the image only when it's really needed?

Comment: WA_OpaquePaintEvent and WA_TranslucentBackground makes it slightly faster (for some reasons), but the image is still repainted. This doesn not work.

Comment: what happen if you put `BackgroundLayer` and `ForegroundLayer ` into `Rectangle { children: [] }`

Comment: No changes with `Rectangle { children: [] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you expect any other kind of behavior? Qt doesn't keep the images of every declarative item for you, it'd be prohibitively expensive in terms of memory. You have the option of enabling this, though: perhaps you should. See the [cacheMode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setCacheMode) documentation.

When any item needs to be updated, everything underneath and intersecting the **update rectangle** has to be repainted too, in the Z order from bottom to top. If there are any widgets underneath the `QGraphicsView` and if the view itself is translucent, then these widgets will have to be repainted as well.

If you have knowledge exactly of what area needs to be updated, you should use that knowledge: call `QGraphicsItem::update(const QRectF &)` to indicate the bounds of what needs updating. Otherwise, with a null rectangle, the update region spans the whole item.

Also ensure that the `QGraphicsView`'s `updateMode` is set to `MinimalViewportUpdate`.

Under the covers, all `QGraphicsItem` instances and all `QWidget` instances all paint on an internal `QImage` that is then blitted or swapped into the underlying native window. They paint in back-to-front Z order, and the only widgets or items that are skipped are those that are completely contained under an opaque widget or item.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but, isn't there a way to at least limit the drawing area so I don't have to repaint the whole image? I know about setClipRect(), and it's not a solution. If I f.ex. draw a diagonal line from top-left to bottom-right corner, the whole screen is repainted, although only a small fraction of it really changed.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer** : Just use a `QPixmap` converted once from `shownImage`

```
void BackgroundLayer::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QWidget* widget)
{
    painter->drawPixmap( QRectF(dx1, dy1, dx2-dx1, dy2-dy1), shownPixmap, QRectF(sx1, sy1, sx2-sx1, sy2-sy1) );
}
```

**Explanation** :

painting pixmaps on screen is much faster than images. The other choices may not work or are way too complex.

Paint events propagate from the top widgets to their children, recursively.
Basically Qt is given a rectangle to paint, and every widget inside this rectangle will receive a paint event.

I am sure what you want to achieve might be doable in some specific cases with widget attribute hacking, but ***I fail to see how you can do it here without having old paint artifacts from the ForegroundLayer***.

Let say you have two lines `AB` et `CD`.

- After the first call to paint you only want to see line `AB`
- After the p1, p2 have been updated you only want to see line `CD`

In order to prevent you from seeing the line AB when painting `CD`, Qt **has to** clear the entire background in the rectangle being painted. If for some reason `BackgroundLayer` doesn't paint, the background image will disappear.